# How do I prevent a JTable from taking a certain input in the specified column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to get a `JTable` to only accept input in a certain format for each column. For example, in a table with 5 columns the ones at indexes 3 and 4 should only accept numeric values.

I know about `RowFilter` and `RowFilter.regexFilter(...)` because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926552/filter-dynamically-jtable-by-column-value), but that hides the entire row instead of just discarding the change and even prevents yet empty rows from showing up right after adding them. This is how I've tried to use it (aka an example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create empty table with 5 columns
    JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new String[][] {}, new String[] { "String", "String", "String", "Num", "Num" }));

    // Create a new table row sorter
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());

    // Filter columns 4 and 5 to only contain numbers
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("[0-9]+", 3, 4));

    // Apply the sorter to the table
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

    // Boilerplate JFrame setup in case you want to run this
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MRE");
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
    addRow.addActionListener((event) -> ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(new String[] {}));
    contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    contentPane.add(addRow);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

TL;DR: I want cells to restore their previous value if the one entered isn't allowed or to not even accept bad input in the typing phase.

Comment: I'd say provide a suitable cell editor.

Comment: *For example, in a table with 5 columns the ones at indexes 3 and 4 should only accept numeric values.* - This has nothing to do with a RowSorter. You need to override the `getColumnClass()` method to return `Integer.class` for those columns. The table will choose an Integer editor that will only allow numeric values.

Comment: *"I modified my code to better fit the description of a mre."* Strange as it may seem, the [edit] which reduced the code snippet further is even *less* like an MRE / SSCCE. The thing is (& this is a common misunderstanding), it is not *all about* minimal / short. *"I managed to do it"* Congrats on solving the problem & +1 for reporting back. Having said that, please revisit both the [mre] **& especially** the page on the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (which goes into more detail) to review the other elements that constitute the MRE / SSCCE labels. Posting one will *help others* to *help you*.

Comment: @AndrewThompson *"even less like an mre"*. You're right, it is. Because the first version of this post was almost the best mre you could provide for this question, and I hope **this time you let me explain why**. Let's take a look at each point of the SSCCE, shall we? *Short*: 25 lines with comments and gaps: far below 100 lines. *TfT, PrS and SC*: Every single line in this example has it's purpose and contributes to making it the most runnable it could ever be. *Correct*: Some of the lines might be too long, but it doesn't hurt readability and otherwise formatting is great.

Comment: Forgive me for sounding cocky, but I'm kind of limited by comment length here. Essentialy what I'm saying is that this example fulfills almost every requirement in the links you posted and should therefore be considered a valid mre. If you think it doesn't, then please explain why. Oh and for the record, I rolled back to the original version of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it, by overriding the `editingStopped(ChangeEvent e)` method of JTable. You're probably supposed to do that with a `TableCellEditor`, but I found this to be easier:

```
public class MyTable extends JTable {

    // Contains the check for each column
    private final Map<Integer, Function<String, Boolean>> checks = new HashMap<>();

    public STable(TableModel model) {
        super(model);

        // Fill the map
        checks.put(0, (str) -> ...);
        checks.put(3, (str) -> ...);
        checks.put(4, (str) -> ...);
    }

    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
        String value = getCellEditor().getCellEditorValue().toString();

        final Function<String, Boolean> checker = checks.get(getSelectedColumn());
        if (checker != null && !checker.apply(value))
            getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
        else
            super.editingStopped(e);
    }

}
```

Also, I didn't try it, but camickr's suggestion of overriding `getColumnClass(int column)` sounds like it could work well. I didn't try it because I needed more complexity than that.